# How to tell if network cable is LSZH

Tags: layer1, cable, cabling

I just bought a 305 meter Cat 6a S/FTP LSZH Solid network cable. The cable I received is a Deltaco TP-53 cable, but I cannot see anywhere that this cable is really LSZH (Low Smoke Zero Halogen). I looked at the TP-53 specifications: https://www.deltaco.se/sites/cdn/InformationDocumentsLibrary/TP-53.pdf and it does not say LSZH anywhere.

So I am wondering if the cable is truly LSZH, how do I tell?

Comment: Removed the off-topic home networking. If the cable is plenum-rated, it should say so, and that would be required for any cable in a plenum space. It is only important if you are intending to run it in a plenum space.

Comment: Thanks @RonMaupin I guess in that case it means that it is not LSZH, but LDPE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Finnish and European sites for Deltaco lists it as "Halogen Free", which would be similar to LSZH. It's an outdoor rated cable by the looks of it, so I'd wager it's not plenum rated. Best course of action is to call/e-mail Deltaco and ask.

http://www.deltaco.eu/en/products/deltaco/cables-adapters/network-cables/cat6a/installation-drum/TP-53